# Npm publish does not trigger a npm hook

Tags: npm, hook, slack

The problem:

I've defined a slack hook, which is connected to our slack workspace. It work perfectly fine to invoke with curl from my terminal with a hello world message, nice!

So now I would like to add a npm hook with the slack hook's endpoint. I add the hook:
`npm hook add <scope> <endpoint> <secret>`. I check to see if it's added, it is. I publish a new package version with the given scope. I get an email about the update, but the hook is not triggered. I check the npm hook list to see if the hook has been updated, I've got "never triggered". For the old hook status I have it as "triggered 3 days ago" and a "400", but it never triggered the slack hook.

Expected: The npm publish command trigger the npm hook which in turn trigger the slack hook.

Actual: No npm hook trigger, no slack hook triggered.

What I've tried:
Removed the npm hook and added it again. Reinstall slack app to workspace channel. Added another scope to npm hook list.

Some code:
The invokation of the slack hook is done like so: `curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/<id>/<id>/<id>`, which works fine.

When checking the npm hook ls I get:

```
You have 2 hooks configured.
┌──────────┬──────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id       │ target               │ endpoint                                                                        │
├──────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ qfifmcgk │ @@<first-scope>           │ https://hooks.slack.com/services/<id>/<id>/<id> │
│          ├──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│          │ triggered 3 days ago │ 400                                                                             │
├──────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ jarhdqdc │ @@<second-scope>       │ https://hooks.slack.com/services/<id>/<id>/<id> │
│          ├──────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│          │ never triggered                                                                                        │
└──────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

How can I troubleshoot this? Thanks!

Update: I've redirected the endpoints to a apigw => lambda which triggers the slack endpoint, that seems to work. BUT! The actual npm triggering is very (!) slow. I published a package on 2022-03-22 14:52, but the trigger was initialised 2022-03-23 23:33, 2 days later. Anyone knows what might cause this?